# Vba to sum below header

Tags: vba

I need to sum a specific range of data below a header. The range of  data is dynamic and could be different from sheet to sheet.

For example it the header could be ""sales" in column A. Then it should sum the values above in column H. Next header could be "operations" then it should sum the values below "sales" and above "operations" in column H. The values always starts on row 10. But the first header could change from time to time.

Is there any vba formula to solve this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Won't a simple SUMIF work for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're column H data looks like this

```
    H
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   sales
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   operations
```

and A14 is blank, A15 contains "sales", and A16 contains "operations", then use this formula in B15 and fill down

```
=SUM(IF(ISBLANK(A14),$H$10,INDEX($H$10:$H$18,MATCH(A14,$H$10:$H$18,FALSE),1)):INDEX($H$10:$H$18,MATCH(A15,$H$10:$H$18,FALSE),1))
```

It uses INDEX and MATCH to find the headings in column H. If the cell above is blank, it assumes you want to start at the top, which is H10. Otherwise it looks for the previous header and the current header and sums everything between them.

```
         A          B
14
15    sales         4
16    operations    3
```